# Role of the prior in Linear Discriminant Analysis

Tags: maximum-likelihood, prior, discriminative-models

I am trying to understand probabilistic generative models a bit better. I am looking at linear discriminant analysis for $C = 2$ classes.

According to what I've seen, the likelihood function can be written like this:

$ p(\vec{y},\mathbf{X} | q, \vec{˜\mu}_1, \vec{˜\mu}_2, \mathbf{\Sigma}) = \prod_{i=1}^{N} \left [ qN(\vec{x}_i|\vec{\mu}_1, \mathbf{\Sigma} ) \right ]^{y_n} - \left [ (1-q)N(\vec{x}_i|\vec{\mu}_2, \mathbf{\Sigma} ) \right ]^{1-y_n}$

I don't understand how the priors are treated.

Why, e.g., is the prior $q = p(C_1)$ for class 1 part of the likelihood function and treated like another parameter that needs to be found via maximum likelihood?

If it is a parmeter of the likelihood function, doesn't that mean it needs to be a parameter of the Gaussian?

My understanding of MLE is: I have *one* distribution with n parameters and I find the ML estimate for each of them by deriving and minimizing.

I thought that combining the likelihood with a prior is Maximum A-Posteriori estimation.